# Change the height of the UIWebView according to the content size

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview

I am creating a webview to display some text in my app.

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(lblContent.frame.origin.x, 
                          lblContent.frame.origin.y,
                          lblContent.frame.size.width,
                          lblContent.frame.size.height);

NSString *htmlText = HTML_DIV_TAG;
htmlText = [htmlText stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@%@", _artistDetail.strContent, @"</div>"];
htmlText = [htmlText stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"''" withString:@"'"];

UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:frame];
[webView loadHTMLString:htmlText baseURL:nil];
webView.scrollView.bounces = NO;
[self addSubview:webView];
```

This is the set of codes that i put it in to my app.

But  need to adjust the height of the web view according to the content size.

Answer (score 1):

If you set `webview.delegate = self` you can add the `UIWebViewDelegate` protocol method `webViewDidFinishLoad:` and invoke a small bit of javascript to determine the height:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    NSString *output = [webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body. scrollHeight;"];
    NSLog(@"height: %@", output);
}
```

Another method would be to determine the webView's scrollView `contentSize` in this method, since that should fit the entire website by the time this method is called.

The only problem with this method, is that this method is called when the *page* finishes loading. Images are handled differently, which means that the webView might change sizes due to images that finish loading.

Answer (score 1):

try -

```
 float height=   [iText sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"FontSpecifiedInTheHtmlText" size: -SpecifiedInHTMLText- constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(320, 100000)lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap].height;
```

after u get the height of the content text, u can set the frame/bounds of the WebView.

Answer (score 0):

You may want this:

```
[webView.scrollView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 20, 0)];
```

Answer (score 0):

UIWebview  is scrollable. So when you open a page in UIWebview u need not adjust the height according to the content of the page. You can see all the content by scrolling the UIWebView. You should check that user interaction is enabled for your webview.